# Run action only the first time the Home page is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application. I want to load a temporary table on SQL Server when the users first access the application. After that, I would like that the user kept using the same temporary table while he is on the application.

I would like that this specific action that loads my temp table were run just once - Otherwise I would be recreating the temporary table and the inserts on sql with no need -, so I believe it's necessary to basically find out whether it's the first time my Index page loads for that user (??), If so, how can I do this? If not, how can I handle this with ASP.NET MVC?

The SQL Server bit doesn't matter for the question really. It's just an overview of what I am doing. All I need to know is how I make sure **my specific controller action only runs once and in the start of my user session**.

Re-editing: I made a mistake, my question was on the scope of the application while it should be on the scope of the user session.

Comment: Have you considered using caching?

Comment: what do u mean by temporary table?

Comment: @Jenninha Not exactly got you point, but you can put data in application cache in Application_Start event in Global.asax file and then you can access it across your application..

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question. I think when I said temporary table it caused confusion. My temporary table is on SQL Server, I don't need to worry about it on my application. I just want to make sure I don't try to recreate it as it would take unnecessary time.

Comment: Let me know if I need to be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Jenninha you have to create one table per users, or one temporary table for all users?

Comment: @CarlosCorralCarvajal - One temporary table per user, but this can be different from time to time BUT it will never be different before the user closes the application. That is why I don't want to run the action that will (re)create the temporary table twice or more.

Comment: Another option is lazy creation on access of the table - not a fan of heavy work over network on startup.

Comment: Jenninha have you thought on using a session var to decide if you have to create a new table or not?, in this case you always call the action but inside the action you could decide. Other posibility is to use session_start in the global.asax

Comment: I will first try doing it in Application_start then and see. I will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: But I think Application_start launch only one, time when App start, if you need a table per users it won't work for you.

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: @CarlosCorralCarvajal , you are right, I cannot use Application_start. Now I realise that I cannot do how I was planning before. I will now try to make another page, the same as my home page, but with another address that will not have the action that would recreate and readd the rows in my temporary table. So then the user can come back to the home page during his session without rerunnig what is unnecessary. I think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application_Start` method in Global.asax. But this code will run everytime you application starts, so probably you have to check if table exist.
You can do this with following code:

```
IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' -- can be other schema
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'))
BEGIN
    --Create table insert rows, etc
END
```

Comment: I already do something like this. It's not a problem if my table is recreated (dropped and created) when the user starts the application another time. My only worry is that if the user comes back to the beginning (Home/Index) everything is done again unnecessarily.
I will look up on what I can do in Application_Start then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try in global.asax Session_start(Object sender, EventArgs E) and Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E)

Create you table in session_Start, delete your table in Session_End().
Tell me if that works

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is to have a repository for the data, and set it to a session variable (could be a database table or whatever, so long as it's tied to the session). Then load it from the data store on the first call, then load it from cache/session from that point on. For example:

```
public SomeTableRepository
{
    private SomeTable _someTable;

    public SomeTable {
        get {
          if (_someTable != null)
              return _someTable;
          else if (Session["SomeTable"] != null)

              return (SomeTable)Session["SomeTable"];
          else
          {
              _someTable = GetDataFromDatabase();
              Session["SomeTable"] = _someTable;
              return _someTable;
          }
        }
        set {
            _someTable = value;
            Session["SomeTable"] = _someTable;
        }
    }
}
```